# Fetch user image android json , tried all stack and google examples but doesnt fit my query

Tags: android, json, image

This is my json response while fetching data:
But the problem is Profilepicture, how i could get the image. Rest thing i know how to get and i am getting.But profilepicture i cant get.
Can anyone suggest or post some example, it would be a great help

```
Data":[{"User":{"Devicetoken":"","Profilepicture":"one","Availibility":"0","Id":"3","Skypeid":"ssssss"}}
```

Comment: You are not receiving an image, you are receiving a String with value of "one". You can't get an image from there...

Comment: You have to use Async task to download the image and set that image to the imageView. use the Async task in ur adapter. By the way what are you using list view or Recyclerview

Comment: I know, but response from php web service is like this, any idea what way it can be downloaded ?

Comment: listview. but how can i download the image with just name ?

Comment: You can't. Talk to the server guy for him to send you the actual image, instead of a String. Ask him to send you a Base64 with the image.

Comment: If in response i get encoded image string, then can i download .I know how to fetch encoded image from response and decode back to image. is that a possible way ?

Comment: It's THE way to get it.